# simple partial derivative of constant times matrix?

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Is the partial derivative of $cX$ w.r.t the real matrix $X$, given by $c$ or by $cI$, where $I$ is the identity, and $c$ is a constant scalar? please give a simple reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

$f(X)=cX$. Let $A$ a matrix. Since $f$ is linear map we have $f'(A)=f$. That means: $$(\forall X \in \mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)) \quad f'(A)(X)=cX$$
Since : $$f'(A)(X)=\sum_{ij} x_{ij} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ij}}(A)=\sum_{ij}x_{ij}(cE_{ij}) $$
we have :
$$(\forall i,j \in \{1,...,n\}) \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ij}}(A)=cE_{ij} $$

Wher $E_{ij}$ is the matrix having all entries zero except the entry of line $i$ and colonne $j$ who is $1$.(This means, forall $i,j,k,\ell \in \{1,...,n\}$ we have using Kronnecker symbol :  $(E_{ij})_{k\ell}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}$)

Comment: so can you add in first line if it is $c$ or $cI$, before the proof?